# Rendering a background image matching window frame, and under navigationTitle, in visionOS

Tags: swiftui, navigationbar, visionos

I managed to render a full width / height background with a modifier that looks like this.-

```
.background {
    AsyncImage(
        url: url,
        transaction: Transaction(animation: .easeIn)
    ) { phase in
        if let image = phase.image {
            image
            .resizable()
            .scaledToFill()
        } else if phase.error != nil  {
            EmptyView()
        } else {
            ProgressView()
        }
    }
    .containerRelativeFrame([.horizontal, .vertical])
}
```

But it still gets clipped by the navigation title bar. I'm aware I could just hide the full `navigationBar` with `.navigationBarHidden(true)` and then render the title and back button myself but, is it possible to keep the native `navigationBar` and render my background behind it?

Answer (score 1):

Finally `.ignoresSafeArea()` modifier did the trick.